# What should I know about cookies domain and scope for security purposes?

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, multi-tenant

Where can I learn (or what is) about a cookie's scope to avoid CSRF and XSS attacks for authenticated users?

For example, if I have a multi-tenant system where a single user can be access to one or more sites what is more secure:

- company1.hoster.com
- company2.hoster.com
- company3.hoster.com

or

- www.hoster.com/company1
- www.hoster.com/company2
- www.hoster.com/company3

What happens if I set a cookie at "hoster.com"?

Comment: I think you mean XSS (Cross site scripting). CSRF is a request forgery, and it doesn't matter (unless checked by the attacked domain) where the request originated from (and you can spoof the origin anyway). XSS have a same origin policy which is a javascript restriction, read upon that

Comment: Thank you.  I'll look into how same origin applies to those scenarios above...

Answer (score 5):

You can restrict the validity scope of cookie in the [domain](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.3) and the [path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.4) separately. So you could set a cookie in both scenarios that is only valid for that specific domain/path combination:

1. To set a cookie for `//company1.example.com/` only:

   ```
    Set-Cookie: name=value; Path=/
   ```

   Omitting the *Domain* attribute makes the cookie only valid for the domain that it was set in. And with `Path=/` the cookie is valid for any path that has the prefix `/`.
2. To set a cookie for `//example.com/company1/` only:

   ```
    Set-Cookie: name=value; Path=/company1/
   ```

   Same explanation as for the example above. The only restriction is that you need to use `/company1/` instead of `/company1` as `Path=/company1` would be equivalent to `Path=/` and thus would make the cookie also valid for `/company2` and `/company3`.

And to avoid that the cookie can be read via JavaScript (reducing the assets accessible using XSS), set the [*HttpOnly* attribute](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.6).

Answer (score 0):

The [Open Web application security project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management) publishes lots of valuable information about secure web application development.

Cookie's have a scope and path attributes, you would normally not want ot issue cookies for "/" or wildcard hosts *.hoster.com would both be ill-advised.

It's not as simple as this one decision, it's good you thought of security in your design, but security is a process, in every phase of your development.